# fixed banners right and left overlap

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add side banners `160X600` that remain fixed with scrolling but my problem when I make the two `div`s position fixed they overlap although there is float left and right this problem is fixed when specifying position absolute to make it clear this my html.

```
<div class="addsright">content</div><div class="adds">content</div>
```

This my css:

```
.adds{position:fixed;float:left;margin-left:0px;margin-top:60px;z-index:1000;}.addsright{position:fixed;float:right;margin-right:0px;margin-top:60px;z-index:1000;}
```

Comment: you float or you position fixed, both does not work, they overlap because of no position = top, left, bottom, right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating a wrapping div and setting position fixed on that. Here's an example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Hjmva